# Connect windows application to SQL Server througn VPN

Tags: sql, wcf, vpn

We have developed a cloud based POS system which running on more that 75 outlets  and all the transaction data need to be posted every 5 minutes to the relevant database which sits on our head office (POS System is connecting to its own local database). For this we are using windows application which is directly connecting to our head office database through a VPN. But recently one of our clients raised a concern that our head office database is exposed because if anyone sneak to the network (obviously inside the VPN) he could see all CRUD Operations. So by this way he could do anything to head office database.

So we have decided to go  for a WCF solution with encrypted JSON Call. If we use a web service can we eliminate this issueccompletely. Is it the best practice? Please advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several aspects of security to consider in your situation. If your current network topology doesn't limit the VPN client's visibility to just your database server, then yes, I agree that moving to publishing a web service endpoint and using HTTPS would improve security by blocking clients access to other servers on your internal network. However, the web service solution introduces some other considerations. Will you use firewall rules to limit which clients can access the web service? How are you authenticating clients, and how are you protecting those credentials from unauthorized users?

Comment: The client can see the database server only. But the consideration is, if anybody listens to the VPN it is possible to gain access to database server. So we are going to use a web service and this web service will be called by the client with encrypted JSON string and web service will decrypt back the JSON string and will do the rest. Our main intention is to remove the database server from VPN

Comment: "If anybody listens to the VPN" - are you using a site-to-site VPN, so that the entire client network is connected to your HQ? I agree, that's a risk. If you're eliminating the VPN and putting the web service on the public Internet, I'd want some kind of robust client authentication to make sure you're getting data only from your clients. Beyond that, TLS should be enough to make sure the information is not subject to eavesdropping in transit.

Comment: Have you considered encrypting your SQL server connections on the VPN? That would safeguard against eavesdropping even if someone gained access to the VPN connection.

Comment: We considered installing certificate on SQL server and secure all connections. But we need to remove database from the VPN. If we use encrypted string is there any security loop hole?

Comment: I would not encrypt the JSON string itself at the application level. I'd use TLS (SSL) to secure the connection between the client and the web service. That prevents any eavesdropper from learning anything about the communication, other than it's happening. If you try to encrypt just the JSON string at the application level, you will probably end up using a symmetric encryption algorithm, which gives you a key management problem on the client. Using SSL means you don't have to worry about storing a secret key on the client.

Comment: Could you please give me any reference to refer how to implement TLS between windows client and WCF?

Comment: The easiest thing to do is publish your WCF endpoint as an HTTPS URL. Here's one tutorial: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36705/simple-steps-to-enable-HTTPS-on-WCF-WsHttp-bindi .